# How do I show 360 image in a-frame a-scene with custom size?

Tags: meanjs, aframe

I have the code like this

**HTML**

```
<a-scene embedded>
  <a-sky  src="modules/core/client/img/images/some.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

**CSS**

```
a-scene {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

**header**

```
<script src="../../../dist/aframe-master.js"></script>
```

It worked with full screen( without adding embedded to ***a-scene*** tag). After adding ***embedded*** it gave me these bunch WebGL of error and warnings.

```
three.js:17443 THREE.WebGLShader: Shader couldn't compile.
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid
three.js:16803 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: no valid shader program in use
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a wrapper element like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height:600px;width:600px">
    <a-scene embedded style="height:100%;width:100%>
    </a-scene>
</div>
```

live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hg7axfk1/)